# SSIS load 4 Excel tabs

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have an Excel file with 4 tabs: Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3 and Sheet4

In SSIS I want to configure a FEL that will go through those 4 tabs and load them into existing tables: Table1, Table2 and etc. Tables already exist.

One Data Flow Task that I created for one of the tabs works well.
But now I want to create a FEL that will loop through all 4 tabs. Excel tabs could be harcoded in the FEL, perhaps putting them all into one variable. I just don't want to create 4 separate Data Flow tasks, as lets say I would have 25 tabs in the other spreadsheet.

Thank you!

Comment: Do the tabs have identical structure? If not, then you would need to do one DFT for each tab.

Comment: Tabs have different settings. So you are saying it is not feasible to do a loop in this scenario?

Comment: Not feasible would be a very broad term, so I would avoid saying that; there may be a way using BIML or using pure .net code. But I have not used it. If I were you, I would implement them separately. I would suggest you to do the same. I would look forward to someone with a different opinion, or how you finally ended up finishing this task.

Comment: Thanks, creating them separately.